# Order integration integral and two series

Tags: probability, integration, sequences-and-series

Define the Haar system as $H_1=\Bbb{1}_{[0,1]}$ and $H_r=2^{\frac{j-1}{2}}\bigl(\Bbb{1}_{[r-,r]}-\Bbb{1}_{(r,r^+]}\bigr)$ where $r$ is a dyadic number, and $r^{\pm}=r\pm\frac{1}{2^j}.$

Let $W(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty X_n\langle H_r,\Bbb{1}_{[0,s]}\rangle$ where $(X_n)$ are independants normal variables.

I would like to prove that $\Bbb{E}(W(s)W(t))=\min(t,s).$

If I am corect, $$\Bbb{E}(W(s)W(t))=\Bbb{E}\bigl(\sum_{n,m=0}^\infty X_nX_m\langle H_n,\Bbb{1}_{[0,s]}\rangle \langle H_m,\Bbb{1}_{[0,t]}\rangle\bigr)$$

Now, Suppose I can switch the two series: $$\Bbb{E}(W(s)W(t))=\sum_{n,m=0}^\infty\Bbb{E}\bigl(X_nX_m\bigr)\langle H_n,\Bbb{1}_{[0,s]}\rangle \langle H_m,\Bbb{1}_{[0,t]}\rangle.$$

As $\Bbb{E}\bigl(X_nX_m\bigr)=0$ if $n\ne m, 1$ if $n=,$  we have, using Parseval's identity, $$\Bbb{E}(W(s)W(t))=\langle\Bbb{1}_{[0,t]},\Bbb{1}_{[0,s]}\rangle$$ which is the result.

I think it's correct.

> How can I justify the change of the order of integration with the two series?
>
> I am not sure what I have to check, is it $\sum_{n,m=0}^\infty\Bbb{E}\bigl(\vert X_nX_m\vert\bigr)<\infty ?$